# Extremely slow simulator (input does not register, scrolling is very slow / laggy / jerky)

Tags: xcode, performance, ios-simulator

I have a very perplexing problem.  I have the 2018 i7 Mac Mini with 32GB RAM and 512GB SSD.  I'm using this with a 43" 4K monitor in full 4K resolution (1:1 pixel mapping, non Retina mode).

I'm finding that scrolling is really laggy / jerky / slow and it doesn't seem to register clicks well.  I've created a short video here: https://youtu.be/2wc908ftvko

I've discovered the following. When setting the screen resolution in Settings:

- 1920x1080 No warning
- 2560x1440 (warning: Using a scaled resolution may affect performance.)
- 3008x1692 (warning: Using a scaled resolution may affect performance.)
- 3360x1890 (warning: Using a scaled resolution may affect performance.)
- 3840x2160 No warning

What's strange is that I ONLY see performance issues in 3840x2160, even though there should not be any extra calculations because it's 1:1 pixel mapped. All other modes should require extra calculations.

Stranger still, everything else (Expose, Mission Control, Spaces, etc) is smoother in 3840x2160 than in any other resolutions. It's only the Simulator that's slow.

And even stranger, the problem goes away if I connect by monitor to BOTH the USB-C and HDMI port on the Mac Mini and ONLY IF the monitor is set to HDMI as the input source.

I've tried different cables and different ports, but this is the only way the problem will go away. I've also tried attaching the monitor to the 2015 MBP via DisplayPort and it has the exact same problem at the 3840x2160 resolution.

Is this a Xcode bug? Is there some setting I don't know about? Or is this because of the slow integrated GPU of the Mac Mini -- if so, would something like this be resolved by an eGPU?

I also made sure to check that Debug -> Slow Animations is definitely off

Comment: There was a bug with Xcode 10 and 10.1 that caused Simulator.app to eat a lot of CPU when processing input for  iPhone Xʀ. It was more pronounced with trackpads. This should be resolved with Xcode 10.2

Answer (score 0):

After much time wasted, this seems to be a bug with the iPhone XR and XS Max simulator at a certain resolution. Everything is fine with the iPhone X simulator.

Other simulators still have performance problems though, but not as pronounced.